# Persisting remote JSON with CoreData

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, persistence

I am able to display JSON successfully to a user, I now wish to be able to display this same information to users who reload my app but are offline. I've read several tutorials on coreData but I am unable to find the correct answers to the below:

1. Does a coredata entity have to have the same amount of attributes as the JSON it is representing has keys?
2. If my JSON has a key which represents a key word within coreData (for example: `description`, which forces me to call this attribute something else), how do I link this back up to my core model?
3. How can I represent a custom array created in my model within my coredata entity?

For reference, I have the below model based off of my JSON. The only keys I actually make use of in my app are `description`, `list_price`, `images` & `title`.

```
struct Item: Codable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let listPrice: String
    let ageRestricted: Bool
    let volume: Int?
    let createdAt: String
    let attributes: [Attributes]
    let images: Images

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title
        case description
        case listPrice = "list_price"
        case ageRestricted = "age_restricted"
        case volume
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case attributes
        case images
    }
}

struct Attributes: Codable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
}

struct Images: Codable {
    let theSize: TheSize?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case theSize = "300"
    }
}

struct theSize: Codable {
    let src: String
    let url: String
    let width: Int
}
```

Comment: did you create a NSManagedObject?

Comment: Not yet - on my first question, would it have to contain *every* key from the JSON even if I am not using every JSON key in my app?

Comment: No you do not need to parse every key, only the ones you need

Comment: I do not understand your second question, regarding your third question you can use relationships